# My Launcher won't continue downloading after a period of time

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues

I recently downloaded LoL and I've had some issues on the "step 2/2 updating league of legends" causing me to (still) not being able to get in. The KBPS keeps dropping to 0 and won't go back up, even after hours. I've looked around the Internet, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you Mac or PC?

Comment: It's a lenovo 

Comment: Okay, normally, when this problem happens it continues after a short while sometimes after 30min. Try running it as Administrator and make sure your firewall isn't blocking the launcher.

Comment: Actually I tried to turn off the firewall while finishing but it still doesn't work. Also I let it run all day while I was in school. Still won't pick up -_-

Comment: I've experienced the same issue. I've waited 10 hours during the working day but no change. After a clean reinstall everything worked fine for me.

Comment: I reinstalled yesterday. I got further, but then it stopped at around 200MB

Comment: Do you have steam or origin in parallel open? They leech on the line which could provoke a timeout.

Comment: Doesn't look like it... weird. I guess it could be the computer, even though I haven't had other problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of these are going to be super simple, but may as well try 'em. They're in the order I reccomend doing them in. Note that you can do many at the same time.:

- Are you installing from the same file each time? If so, download a new installer.
- Restart your PC
- Run installer as Admin
- Enable / Disable P2P: In your client, click the gear icon in the top-right, and then check or uncheck "Enable Peer to Peer Transfer":

[image: Enabling or Disabling P2P]

- Close out all other unneeded programs -- like, all of them
- I don't know how you're uninstalling League, but try doing it with a free trial of [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). Then reinstall.
- Contact [League support](https://support.riotgames.com/)

Again, you have probably tried many of these already; sorry if this answer is redudant.

Comment: To be honest I got it downloaded on my new computer. But then I bumped into a new problem - when I click "launch" the game closes down and nothing happens

Comment: Huh. Try redownloading without P2P and with Admin rights. If that doesn't work, ask League support.

Comment: The P2P hasn't affected it at all...  neither did admin. Guess I'll see if I can get in contact with league support

Comment: OK, good luck :]

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what this problem is, but I can't see anything like this on their support side. Thanks for your help tho 

Comment: You can email them, too.

Comment: Oh really? Didn't notice.. Aha  well thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it in Low Spec Mode. Only way I could get it to download.